# Run sh script inside docker container from Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This is a sample `Jenkinsfile`:

```groovy
docker.image.inside() {
  PWD = sh (
    script: 'pwd',
    returnStdout: true
  ).trim()
}
```

When I run this Jenkinsfile the script runs on the host machine instead of container. I want to run this inside the docker container.

Comment: How do you know it is not executing inside of the container?

Comment: I cross checked using pwd command.

Answer (score 1):

`pwd` is going to print out the same directory as the workspace on the host. This is because Jenkins mounts the workspace as a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) to the same exact path in the container and then runs commands in that path by using [`--workdir`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#workdir) option. The directory is shared between the host and the container, and also has the same name. From [this documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) you still see a few notes about the Docker pipeline plugin:

> For `inside()` to work, the Docker server and the Jenkins agent must use the same filesystem, so that the workspace can be mounted.

Example: If you do something like the below you will see that the command is executed in the container and not on the agent.

```
docker.image('alpine:3.7').inside {
  sh 'cat /etc/alpine-release'
}
```

Comment: Actually I was trying to execute a python script `COV_BADGE = sh (
                  script: "./coverage-badge/coverage_badge/__main__.py",
                  returnStdout: true
              ).trim()` But I got an error stating file not found though I can see file by  separately running `docker run`

Comment: Did you checkout the source code first? Or where are you expecting the file? Jenkins Docker pipeline does some strange things when executing, You should check your build logs for a `docker run` command to see what options are being provided.

Comment: I did. I build image during Jenkins's build process so I used that image to check what is wrong but seems nothing.

Comment: You are going to have to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because the plugin is doing what I expect, and your question is currently lacking information about what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: I found the issue, Jenkins use current workspace as workdir and I have defined different workdir in my Dockerfile so there was some misunderstanding. Is there any way to disable Jenkins's default workdir?

Comment: Had same issue. You can set the `workdir` like in here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46636 pretty much: `dir('/app') { steps { } }`